# similar tool like Visual Round Trip Analyzer for Linux

Tags: linux

Wireshark looks good is there any thing that can give a graphical view like Visual Round Trip Analyzer where it shows the number of packets/requests per port?

I am ok if some one can tell me if the data from Wireshark can be used to get such a result.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP traffic: You need the Net tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).  [See the firebug Network docs](http://getfirebug.com/network) for details

General traffic observation: use

- [`pktstat -nT`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pktstat) (for short term monitoring)
- [`ntop`](http://ntop.org/) (longer term monitoring)

Comment: but that only pickup http request i need to pickup UDP and tcp traffice

Comment: what problem are you solving with this information?

Comment: i just need to monitor the traffic coming to the system and through what ports what request are coming

Comment: please see my update

Answer (score 0):

Does [Statistics→Conversations](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatConversations.html) or [Statistics→Endpoints](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatEndpoints.html) do what you need? You can list addresses, ports, packet counts and byte counts for various protocols. The Endpoints tables also support GeoIP with some additional configuration. You can dump the same information out on the command line using [TShark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) via the `−z conv` flags.