# What is the tool for monitoring network traffic in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring

So far, I have been using Windows OS and I have used `netmon` and `Visual round trip analyzer`. Now I have to shift to Linux systems.

What is the equivalent tool in a Linux environment.

Comment: hey it would be cool if you derscribe exactly what usage you have for the tool, there are many different tools in linux with lots of functionality. For Roundtrip stuff you can use Tcpdump, otherwise i would also recommend Wireshark.

Comment: Wireshark looks good is there any thing that can give a graphical view like Visual Round Trip Analyzer where it shows the number of packets/requests per port?

Comment: please do not double post: http://serverfault.com/questions/400067/similar-tool-like-visual-round-trip-analyzer-for-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)? It's a network analyzer which can capture and display any network traffic - and it works on Windows too.

Comment: Wireshark can load "`tcpdump`" files and both are based on `libpcap`, so why not point out both?

Answer (score 3):

I am partial to iptraf, should be available in most distribution repositories!

http://iptraf.seul.org/

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want to get.
Just a small list of tools to start from:

- wireshark (ethereal) -- a great tool to analyze the network traffic
- tshark — wireshark with a console interface
- tcpdump — lightweight traffic sniffer and analyzer; almost always is installed
- trafshow — a tool that shows you which traffic goes through an interface and where it goes
- different netflow tools — they do the same but in more enterprise fashion

Comment: don't forget iftop

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see if there is any traffic or errors on network interfaces in real-time, then something like the following could be handy:

```
$ watch -d ifconfig
```

Comment: Also `vnstat` to keep record of the usage ...

Answer (score 1):

Check out ntop: http://www.ntop.org/

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew Gall responded, iptraf is always a handy tool to determine bandwidth usage on a network interface basis. Also iftop is another utility, i will recommend reading the below post.
[Network traffic and bandwidth monitoring in linux](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-iptraf-and-iftop-monitor-and-analyse-network-traffic-and-bandwidth)

Answer (score 0):

**Wireshark**. You should be happy with it.
But remember to setup Wireshark to run as non root user:
http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/7523/ubuntu-machine-no-interfaces-listed

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is the way to go, but when you install it on Linux you may also need to install a package called  "wireshark-gnome".   After installation, run it by typing "wireshark" into a terminal.